# Generate URL symfony 2 empty value

Tags: php, symfony

I have this generate url link in symfony 2 :

```
$route = $this->generateUrl('mail', array('from' => $oSender->getSettingValue(),
        'adres' => (empty($aInfo['executorEmail']) ? 'info@blablabla.nl' : $aInfo['executorEmail']),
        'subject' => 'Werkbonnen project ' . $aInfo['projectName'] . ' week ' . $aInfo['workOrderWeeknumber'],
        'name' => $aInfo['executorName'],
        'filename' => $filename,
        'filename2' => '',
        'workOrderId' => $id));
```

route annotation:

```
 /**
 * @Route("/workorder/mail/{from}/{adres}/{subject}/{name}/{filename}/{filename2}/{workOrderId}", name="mail")
 * @Template()
 */
```

And this function where the generate route is going:

```
public function mailAction(Request $request, $from = '', $adres = '', $subject = '', $name = '', $filename = '', $filename2 = '', $workOrderId) {
// some code here not important

}
```

It keeps saying this :

```
Parameter "filename2" for route "mail" must match "[^/]++" ("" given) to generate a corresponding URL.
```

How can i give a empty value with the generateUrl function in symfony. 
variable filename2 is optional.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Routes are the same as a normal PHP function, that you can't have an empty parameter in the variables passed, when you have other parameters after it.
So with your problem you have two choices;

1. Put the `filename2` parameter at the end of the route, making it optional
2. Keep `filename2` in place, but give it a default value.

If you choose option 2 an example route would be;

```
/**
 * @Route("/workorder/mail/{from}/{adres}/{subject}/{name}/{filename}/{filename2}/{workOrderId}", name="mail", defaults={"filename2" = 0})
 */
```

More information on routes with parameters can be [found here in the Symfony docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html).

Comment: Thanks this is the best solution for this!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass an empty string to a URL parameter. Try something like:

```
$route = $this->generateUrl('mail', array('from' => $oSender->getSettingValue(),
        'adres' => (empty($aInfo['executorEmail']) ? 'info@blablabla.nl' : $aInfo['executorEmail']),
        'subject' => 'Werkbonnen project ' . $aInfo['projectName'] . ' week ' . $aInfo['workOrderWeeknumber'],
        'name' => $aInfo['executorName'],
        'filename' => $filename,
        'filename2' => 'something',
        'workOrderId' => $id));
```

The regular expression is clear, `[^/]++` means "a non empty string that does not contain the character /".

If that parameter can be empty you cannot put it in the URL, you have to use the query string instead:

/your/really/long/url/with/all/your/parameters?filename2=

Answer (score 0):

```
    $route = $this->generateUrl('mail', array(
        'workOrderId' => $id,
        'from' => $oSender->getSettingValue(),
        'adres' => (empty($aInfo['executorEmail']) ? 'info@blablabla.nl' : $aInfo['executorEmail']),
        'subject' => 'Werkbonnen project ' . $aInfo['projectName'] . ' week ' . $aInfo['workOrderWeeknumber'],
        'name' => $aInfo['executorName'],
        'filename' => $filename,
        'filename2' => ''));
```

Nevermind this is working for me, must give the filename2 parameter as last in the url.